# How to make(improve) a quiz game in C++

Tags: c++

The code is very ugly and it's supposed to form a simple test, but there are some problems..the point is to create a quiz game with ten questions and the idea is to choose and pick answers with the arrows and enter. I would love some suggestions or improvements.

How may I recontstruct it in order to proceed to the next question after clicking the Enter button..so far is available only one question and it checks for correct/incorrect and adds a point +1 to the variable "d".

**Knowledge Level: High School**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   char k;
    int m = 0, d = 0 ;
    const int Up = 72;
    const int Down = 80;
    const int Enter = 13;
    cout<<" 1.Which is the closest planet to the Sun?\n"
        "> A) Mercury\n"
        "  B) Mars\n"
        "  C) Earth\n"
        "  D) Neptune\n";
    do {
        k = getch();
        if(k == Down) {
            m++;
        }
        else if(k == Up) {
            m--;
        }
        if(m>3) {
            m = 0;
        }
        else if(m < 0) {
            m = 3;
        }
        system("CLS");;
        if (m == 0) {
            cout << " 1.What is the closest planet to the Sun?\n"
                 "> A) Mercury\n";
        }
        else {
            cout<<" 1.What is the closest planet to the Sun?\n"
                "  A) Mercury\n";
        }
        if (m == 1) {
            cout << "> B) Mars\n";
        }
        else {
            cout<< "  B) Mars\n";
        }
        if (m == 2) {
            cout << "> C) Earth\n";
        }
        else {
            cout<< "  C) Earth\n";
        }
        if (m == 3) {
            cout << "> D) Neptune\n\n";
        }
        else {
            cout<< "  D) Neptune\n\n";
        }
    } while (k != Enter);
    if (m==0) {
        d++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you would of course check to see if `k=='A'` or `'B'`  or `'C'` or `'D'`. And then see if it was the right answer.  But as an aside, you're going to sit down and think about how to make your program more rhan just a cut-and-paste of the same code 10 times.

Comment: It's `<cstdlib>`, not `<stdlib.h>` in C++. Avoid platform specific ode (`<conio.h>`) to enhance portability (Use a cross platform libarry like ncurses which has a windows port (pdcurses)). Avoid using `system()`, especially for the same reason. Use a suitable data structure for questions and answers. Avoid writing duplicate code but write reusable functions. Use meaningful names for variables, avoid 1-letter-names. Declare/define variables as close to the position they're used. Read questions and answers from a file instead including the strings in your program for flexibility.

Comment: Spencer and Swordfish, thank you so much mates, all the given information is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a data structure that represents a question (and its answer), and create a collection of such structures.
Then you can loop over them or pick one at random or whatever you like.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Question
{
    std::string question;
    std::vector<std::string> answers;
    int correct;
};

std::vector<Question> questions = 
{
    { "What is the moon", {"Cheese", "Fake"}, 0 },
    { "Where's Waldo", {"Over here", "Over there"}, 1}
};

int main()
{
    for (const auto& q: questions)
    {
        std::cout << q.question << "?\n";
        char option = 'A';
        for (const auto& a: q.answers)
        {
            std::cout << option << ") " << a << '\n';
            option += 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Correct answer: " << q.answers[q.correct] << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
What is the moon?
A) Cheese
B) Fake
Correct answer: Cheese

Where's Waldo?
A) Over here
B) Over there
Correct answer: Over there
```

Comment: Thank you! I do really appreciate your help :)